# SpecialCells returns different results depending on size of range

Tags: vba, excel

i really confuse and curious, why with same coding, just with different data quantity, the output can be really different?

```
With Sheets("control deck").Range("A2:A5000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
.FormulaR1C1 = "=r[-1]C"
End With
```

with

```
With Sheets("control deck").Range("A2:A50000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
.FormulaR1C1 = "=r[-1]C"
End With
```

the first output, fill **only** the blanks with the copy of cell's value above
and the second coding, fill **all** the range with copy of  first cell's value

my data :

```
>     1111    | abc    |x
>                      |y
>                      |z
>     
>     1112    | def    |R
>                      |S
>                      |T
>                      |U
```

what i hope come out

> ```
> 1111    | abc    |x
> 1111      abc    |y
> 1111      abc    |z
>
> 1112    | def    |R
> 1112      def    |S
> 1112      def    |T
> 1112      def    |U
> ```

what came out

> ```
>     >     1111    | abc    |x
>     >     1111      abc    |y
>     >     1111      abc    |z
>     >      
>     >     1111    | abc    |R
>     >     1111      abc    |S
>     >     1111      abc    |T
>     >     1111      abc    |U
> ```

anybody know why?

this only happen if the range above 30000 `row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Excel 2007 or earlier, there is a limit to the number of distinct cell areas `SpecialCells` can reference of 8192

As an alternative, try this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set r = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A50000")
    dat = r.FormulaR1C1
    For i = 1 To UBound(dat, 1)
        If dat(i, 1) = "" Then
            dat(i, 1) = "=r[-1]C"
        End If
    Next

    r = dat

End Sub
```

This will be *much* faster, too.

Comment: The limit applies to 8192 distinct cell areas - not individual cells.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in special cells, allegedly fixed in 2010, of 8,192 areas that can be selected.